# Write a recursive LISP function that finds the dot product of two lists of numbers of same length

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

Just started to learn LISP and I'm trying to figure out how to write the following recursive function.

So should I have

```
(DOT-PRODUCT '(1 2) '(3 4)))
```

The output should be 11

I've written the following

```
(defun DOT-PRODUCT (a b)
  (if (or (null a) (null b))
      0
      (+ (* (first a) (first b))
         (DOT-PRODUCT (rest a) (rest b)))))
```

And everything seems to work; however, it still works with lists of different lengths. I want it to just work with lists of numbers that have the same length. Where should I add code that returns "invalid length" should we have such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way is to rewrite the function so that it checks different cases using the conditional form `cond`:

```
(defun dot-product (a b)
  (cond ((null a) (if (null b) 0 (error "invalid length")))
        ((null b) (error "invalid length"))
        (t (+ (* (first a) (first b))
              (dot-product (rest a) (rest b))))))
```

In the first branch of the `cond`, if the first argument is `NIL`, the second one must be `NIL` as well, otherwise an error is generated. In the second branch, we already know that `a` is not `NIL`, so an error is immediately generated. Finally, the result is calculated.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and suggestion for using cond instead of if. That really helps!

Answer (score 3):

Multiply corresponding elements of lists X and Y:

```
(mapcar #'* X Y)
```

Add elements of a list Z:

```
(reduce #'+ Z)
```

Put together: dot product:

```
(reduce #'+ (mapcar #'* X Y))
```

`reduce` and `mapcar` are the basis for the "[MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)" concept, which is a generalization of that sort of thing that includes dot products, convolution integrals and a myriad ways of massaging and summarizing data.

Answer (score -1):

One can increase efficiency by introducing an accumulator variable and turning the standard recursion into a tail recursion. In this example, I used `(labels)` to define the recursion:

```
(defun DOT-PRODUCT (a b)
  (labels ((dp (x y accum)
             (if (or (null x) (null y))
                 accum
                 (dp (rest x) (rest y) (+ accum (* (first x) (first y)))))))
    (if (= (length a) (length b))
        (dp a b 0)
        (error "Invalid length."))))
```